# Es posible subir a un servidor vps una app con back en django y front en react.js?

Tags: reactjs, django, djangorestframework, vps

Desarrolle una web que utiliza react.js y django, y mi duda es si es posible subirla a un servidor vps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sí por medio del proxy reverse en la configuración de tu servidor web, ya sea nginx o apache. debes de realizar el deploy mediante la guía que ellos proporciona.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/

para que te detecte las urls del react debe configurarlo también, en nginx

```
location / {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index  index.html;

     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}
```

te podrías guiar con este artículo, esta bien explicado
https://austinogiza.medium.com/deploying-react-and-django-rest-framework-with-nginx-and-gunicorn-7a0553459500